# Deploying to Heroku using Node NO CSS or JS files found error 404

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, heroku

I am very new to Heroku and need your help. I have tried everything but failed so far.

I am making this app following "Getting mean" book. Everything works apart from CSS and JS.

My layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
 head
 meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
 title= title
 link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css')
 link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

I am getting following error in my browser console:

```
GET damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/css/… damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/:1
GET damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min‌​.js damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/:1
GET damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min‌​.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Can you add more details please. What are the errors you are receiving?

Comment: GET https://damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/css/amelia.bootstrap.css 
damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/:1 GET https://damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/:1 GET https://damp-savannah-84881.herokuapp.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Does the site work locally, on your own computer? Because to me it looks like you haven't set up static routes, like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`  You also need to further indent the stuff under `head` so jade puts it inside <head>.